# How to add EventToCommand in XAML

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light, xml-namespaces

I use Mvvm light(wpf45).

I want add EventToCommand in XAML, I use this

```
xmlns:cmd ="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

but don't add EventToCommand

```
<Button>
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
     <cmd:EventToCommand/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

i get error in `<cmd:EventToCommand/>`

Comment: Did you forget to add the `i` namespace and/or set a reference to the Interaction assemblies?

Comment: No, i add xmlns for `i`. I get error in `cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this reference,

```
xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"
```

you can able to use EventToCommand class.

Hope it helped you :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you should code it like this.

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
 <i:EventToCommand EventName="YourPropertyEvent" Command="YourBinding"/>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```